# How to map values from JSON using Enhanced Enum in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I want to map the values from JSON to an object. One of the properties of my object have the datatype an `Enhanced Enum`. Here is where I'm stuck because I can't manage to map the values from the JSON using the values from the enum.

```
List<MyObject?>? objects = List<MyObject?>.from(json["MyObject"]!.map((x) => MyObject.fromJson(x)));

class MyObject {
  MyObject({
    this.myProperty
  });

  MyEnhancedEnum? myProperty = MyEnhancedEnum.unknown;

    factory MyObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyObject(

        myProperty: json["JSONPropertyValue"] == null
            ? MyEnhancedEnum.unknown
            : 
                //
                // how to map here the value from the JSON result using the Enhanced Enum from below ?  
                // something like myNonEnhancedEnumValues.map[json["JSONPropertyValue"]] 
                //
            ,
    );
}

enum MyEnhancedEnum {
    valueOne("One"),
    valueTwo("Two"),
    valueUnknown("");

    const MyEnhancedEnum(this.value);
    final String value;
}


// The old way is working, but I want to switch to Enhanced Enums available from Flutter 2.17

enum MyNonEnhancedEnum {one, two, unknown}

final myNonEnhancedEnumValues = MyNonEnhancedEnum({
  "One": MyNonEnhancedEnum.one,
  "Two": MyNonEnhancedEnum.two,
  ""   : MyNonEnhancedEnum.unknown
});
```

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: What do prefer  accept null or empty string ?

Comment: My model should accept null as nullsafety value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method.

```dart
MyEnhancedEnum enumFromString(String? input) {
  return MyEnhancedEnum.values.firstWhere(
    (element) => element.key == (input ?? ""),
    orElse: () => MyEnhancedEnum.valueUnknown,
  );
}
```

And pass

```dart
 myProperty: enumFromString(json["JSONPropertyValue")
```

---

Test

```dart
void main() {
  group("should return `MyEnhancedEnum.valueUnknown` ", () {
    test("on null", () {
      final result = enumFromString(null);
      expect(result, MyEnhancedEnum.valueUnknown);
    });
    test("on empty string", () {
      final result = enumFromString("");
      expect(result, MyEnhancedEnum.valueUnknown);
    });
  });
  test("should return `MyEnhancedEnum.valueOne` on `One`", () {
    final result = enumFromString("One");
    expect(result, MyEnhancedEnum.valueOne);
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to generalize more this function ? For example if my object contains 10 properties and each property is of type Enhanced Enum ? I would like to don't rewrite 10 times the same method.

Comment: yes I had made one generic type for my project, let me check it

Comment: try `T? enumFromString<T>(Iterable<T> values, String? value) {
  return values.firstWhere((type) => type.toString().split(".").last == value);
}`

Comment: What is the logic for that `split`. ?

Comment: it is too old one, kinda refactor my project, If i find & remember I will include it. you can create extension

Comment: Do you have any idea what can I add on `orElse: () =>` in the `firstWhere` closure for the above generic enum type? My code is crashing because I don't cover the orElse case and I don't know exactly how to handle it.

Comment: you may wrap with try-catch and return null on generic case, because it is not possible to determine which one will be default unless you fixed some index...